I'm trying to run my Flutter app on my android phone but I keep getting errors related to Gradle
This is part of the log I got:
**`FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:dexBuilderDebug'.


There was a failure while executing work items
A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.dexing.DexWorkAction
> Failed to process: C:\Users[USER]\projeto\build\app\tmp\kotlin-classes\debug, C:\Users[USER]\projeto\build\app\intermediates\javac\debug\classes`**

This is my project's android/build.gradle file:
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

This is my project's android/app/build.gradle file:
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.application'

    ndkVersion "25.2.9519653"

    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.fahad.app"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

I tried to make some modifications on android/app/build.gradle, cleaning flutter cache, and rebuilding the project but I got another error.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
*** What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.6.1.
Searched in the following locations:
- https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.6.1/gradle-7.6.1.pom
- https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.6.1/gradle-7.6.1.pom
Required by:
project :**

This is my updated android/app/build.gradle file:
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.application'

    ndkVersion "25.2.9519653"

    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.fahad.app"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}


Can you check the version of the gradle wrapper in gradle-wrapper.properties?

What Android Studio version are you using? Also, can you show the output of running in the terminal flutter doctor?

@gtxtreme this is the version I'm working with:
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6.1-all.zip

@tomerpacific
Doctor summary:
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.22.1, on Microsoft Windows [versÆo 10.0.19045.4412], locale pt-BR)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Ferramentas de Build do Visual Studio 2019 16.11.36)
[√] Android Studio (version 2023.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.90.0)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
[√] Network resources
• No issues found!

You can try disabling Gradle offline mode
